# Como puedo retornar valores en una funcion con JavaScript sin que se detenga la ejecucion?

Tags: javascript

Quizas la pregunta pueda ser algo basica, pero llevo rato ya buscando en varios lados y no encuentro una respuesta clara. Necesito hacer una funcion con un condicional en JavaScript y que ambas condiciones retornen valores, pero como return detiene la ejecucion de la funcion solo me toma una de las condiciones y no he podido pasar el test del algoritmo por eso. Alguna alternativa? Aqui coloco tambien el codigo:

```
    function obtenerMayor(x, y) {
  if(x < y){
     return x;
  }else if(x > y){
     return y;
  }
  else{
    x = y;
    return x && y;
  }
}
```

Comment: Creo que el problema que tienes es que devuelves el menor de los valores recibidos y no el mayor

Comment: Diria que si lo que pretende esa función es devolver el número mayor de ambos parámetros estas haciendo los dos primeros returns al reves. Aparte de eso no entiendo que pretendes con el ultimo return

Answer (score 2):

Ccomo te dijo Pablo en el comentario, estas devolviendo el valor menor, aunque la función se llama obtenerMayor. Pienso que ese es el problema con el que te topaste.

De paso te comento un par de cosas más sobre el fragmento que publicaste:

1. En la tercera condicion, que es si son iguales, es innecesario hacer ese x = y, porque x ya es igual a y. No necesitas asignarle el valor que ya tiene.
2. La linea **return x && y** solo va a devolver un booleano, en este caso TRUE. ¿Por qué? Pues porque **x && y** es una operación lógica, como podría ser **x > y**. Estas evaluaciones se resuelven a un booleano, y eso es lo que se termina devolviendo. En el caso de **x && y**, lo que estas evaluando es que tanto x como y no sean **undefined** o **null**. Si lo que quieres es devolver el valor, podrías hacer **return x** o **return y**, es indistinto ya que ambos números valen lo mismo.

Comment: Creo que te confundes, el operador lógico `&&` no devuelve true o false, sino que tal como dicen en su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) devolverá el valor del primer operando que encuentre que sea falso, de izquierda a derecha, o bien el valor del último operando si todos son true. Lo que sí hace es evaluarlo como true o false, pero no lo devuelve tal como acabo de explicar. Aquí tienes un ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/o08t4d9u/

Answer (score 0):

Para tener el mayo número solo basta preguntar si `x > y`, si es así, entonces devolver `x`, de lo contrario devolver `y` y ya está.

Si ambos son iguales, se puede retornar cualquiera de los 2 números, así que sigue cumpliendo.

```
function obtenerMayor(x, y) {
    if(x > y) {
        return x;
    } else {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Reduciendo ese bloque `if/else` a ternario:

```
function obtenerMayor(x, y) { 
    return x>y ? x : y;
}
```